# Dynamic jquery selector based on html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<table id="Product">
       <thead>
              <tr>
                    <th>ProductId</th>
                    <th>Productname</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>UnitPrice</th>
              </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

       </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add" data-table="Product" data-url="Product/Add"></button>
```

Then in javascript file:

```
     $('#add').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            var table = $(this).attr("data-table");
            var tableBody = ???; 
            //some logic with tablebody

    });
```

How can i get table body of the table?

Comment: What do you mean by table body? Which table?

Comment: Please check new details

Comment: `var tableBody = $("table tbody")` or `var tableBody = $("#" + table)` What is expected result?

Comment: var tableBody = $("#"+table+" tbody"); this woks, $("table tbody") this pick any (or first) table tag... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.data("url");
    var tableId = $this.data("table");
    var $tableBody = $("#" + tableId + " tbody");
});
```

Read more about jQuery selectors at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Here I'm using the [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#add').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        var table = $(this).attr("data-table");
        var tableBody = $("#" + table).find("tbody"); 
        //some logic with tablebody

});
```

Comment: thanks, this also work         var tableBody = $("#"+table+" tbody");